# Cant get POST data in codeigniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

For some reason I cant seem to get to post data in a codeigniter controller.  I broke it down to a very simple form to test it out, still no luck.  If I use method="get" it works fine.  Anyways, below is the form, the controller/function, and my .htaccess.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Also, I saw a few other similar questions on here, but none of them seemed to have an answer that worked for me.

form:

```
<form id="bundleOrderInfo" name="bundleOrderInfo" action="<?php echo(base_url()); ?>catalog/bundleSubmit" method="post"> 

<input type="text" name ="test" id="test" value="blahblah"></input>
<input type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

controller/function:

```
    public function bundleSubmit()
{
   $this->output->enable_profiler();
   $this->load->model('catalog_model');

   $data['availableCategories']=$this->catalog_model->getCategories();
   $data['availableItems'] = $this->catalog_model->getByCategory($data['availableCategories']);
   $testing = $this->catalog_model->formData();

   $this->load->view('templates/header');
   $this->load->view('templates/menu',$data);

   print_r($_POST);
}
```

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ITPortal/index.php?/$1 [L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ITPortal/index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /ITPortal/index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 6):

action should direct to controller function, if you try FormHelper your life will be much easier

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Try to load models,helpers, libraries at constructor [ __construct() function] it is a good proper way.

**Controller**

```
function __construct()
{
     parent:: __construct();
     $this->load->helper('form'); //loading form helper
     $this->load->model('catalog_model'); //loading your model
}

function bundleSubmit()
{
     $this->catalogmodel->insertFromForm();  //calling your method from model
}
```

Normally you should catch Posted Value in model

**Model**

```
  function insertFromForm()
  {
     $name= $this->input->post('name');
     print_r($name);
     die(); // stop the process here
  }
```

**View**

```
<?php echo form_open('catalog/bundleSubmit','id="bundleOrderInfo" name="bundleOrderInfo"') ;?>
//you can also do this , this should be enough 
//<?php echo form_open('catalog/bundleSubmit')?>

<input type="text" name ="test" id="test" value="blahblah"></input>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>

<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Addition

```
'catalog/BundleSubmit' in form mean means your form posted values will goes to to 'controller/function()' and controller will redirect to a method in model 'model/insertDataFromForm"
```

If you want to know more you can check with CI's table of contents

How things work

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/appflow.html

more info:- https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  the solution ended up actually being that I didnt have rewrite module on in apache (strange thing is it seemed to work for everything except posting data though).  Anyways, thanks for the suggestion, and I definitely need to read more into the user guide.

Comment: Do not ever ask the model to read the superglobal data.  It is the responsibility of the controller to receive the passed in data (POST and GET).  Do not ever print anything from the model, only the view should be printing.  Your model should never `die`.  If you are going to recommend form helper functions, why not write the form fields with helpers too?  There is almost nothing that I would endorse about this answer.